# Send email using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a project but I didn't solve a problem that I got. I'm preparing a form as a modal on my website and I want to user input his email to the form. Everything alright until here but I want something else and that's: SEND LINK AS E-MAIL (NOT VERIFICATION) can you help me? I didn't use PHP before. So, if I can solve this thing with PHP please light me up with sharing how to link a PHP file to an HTML file. Thanks a lot from now :)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. [**Do some research**](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+send+html+mail+site:stackoverflow.com), search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing the following snippet:

```
<a href="mailto:yourEmail@gmail.com?subject=This is the email header&body=This is the body of the email">Send an Email Example</a>
```

This link should provide some more information and examples on using mailto: [Using HTML mailto](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-mailto-links.html)

This answer was quite easy to find. Just like the comments say, make sure you are doing **some** research before asking a question.